# Is there any way to create a listener to accept the errors in the patternlock in gingerbread?

Tags: android

Iam trying to create an app without editing the android os in such a way to notify my app whenever the user enters the patten wrong. is this possible. i was thinking about using a listener that listens to the log of the phone. i am not sure this will work though because iam quite a beginner in android.